# Incorrect resourceBundle value when using JasperFillManager.fillReport

Tags: java, spring-boot, jasper-reports

I have a `my_report.jasper` that contains `resourceBundle="translations"`. The jasper and the translation.properties are in the same folder and it works within jaspersoft studio (I am able to see the defined transalation correctly.

I am integrating this report in a springboot application with the structure:

```
src/main/java/my_package
        MyCodeThatCreatesTheReport.java
src/main/resources/reports
        my_report.jasper
        translations.properties
        translations_es.properties
        translations_en.properties
        translations_hu.properties
```

I am creating the report as:

```
Map<String, Object> jasperParams = new HashMap<>();
ResourceBundle resourceBundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("reports.translations");
jasperParams.put(JRParameter.REPORT_RESOURCE_BUNDLE, resourceBundle);
/* Load the Jasper Report file */
File file = ResourceUtils.getFile("src/main/resources/reports/my_report.jasper");
jasperReport = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObjectFromFile(file.getAbsolutePath());

MyClassBean myClassBean = new MyClassBean();
JRDataSource dataSource = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(List.of(myClassBean));
JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, jasperParams, dataSource);
```

The returns the following error because it does not find the translation.properties:

```
 java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name idioma, locale en_US
```

Changing in the jasper file from `resourceBundle="translations"` to `resourceBundle="reports/translations"` allows me to create the report from springboot but then I loose access from the report to the translations.

Why is the `resourceBundle` not updated when using the `fillReport` function?

```
JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, -->jasperParams<--, dataSource);
```